# Cropping geo pdf in GDAL for use in OruxMaps?

Tags: gdal, geospatial-pdf, oruxmaps

I am attempting to crop geo pdf mapsheet files to the map area, so that they will switch automatically between maps in a program like Oruxmaps. The starting geo pdfs open fine in OM. So far I can use the published python script (cutline.py):

```
from osgeo import gdal
import os
import sys

ds = gdal.Open(sys.argv[1])
neatline_wkt = ds.GetMetadataItem("NEATLINE")
ds = None

f = open('cutline.csv', 'wt')
f.write('id,WKT\n')
f.write('1,"%s"\n' % neatline_wkt)
f.close()

os.system('gdalwarp %s temp.tif ' % sys.argv[1] +
      '-crop_to_cutline -cutline cutline.csv -overwrite')
```

run: *python cutline.py whatever.pdf*

But gdalwrap gives an error on attempted raster geo pdf output, so the above script uses the default geo tif output. Therefore, to get the cropped pdf, I have to run: *gdal_translate -of pdf temp.tif temp.pdf*

Unfortunately after all that, OruxMaps to v. 7.0.17 does not seem to support geo pdfs from GDAL. After refresh maps, OM gives the error “> Can not find GEO info!” (even though the GEO info shows using gdalinfo, and the files open with correct geo referencing in qgis, for example).

So, my question is:

Is there a direct way to get gdal to crop a geo pdf and save the geo pdf format?

Comment: Please refine your post to include a single, focused question. Remember you can always ask another question.

Comment: OK, I asked the 2 questions in 2 separate posts.

Comment: As you already have found out, you need to use gdal_translate after warping.

Comment: Thanks AndreJ. Do you know of any solution for the consequent problem that OruxMaps does not find Geo info in georeferenced pdfs from gdal_translate?

Comment: With input from Orux, geo-referenced pdfs from gdal do load correctly in OM v 7.0.18 beta3; so expect that to work in the released OM v 7.0.18